# Simple apache mod_rewrite just not working

Tags: node.js, apache, mod-rewrite

What I wanted is really simple, but it's just not working.

First the application is running on Node.js, i.e., localhost:8080
And I use Apache mod_rewrite to route the requests to Node.js, like this

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName shopecific.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]
    ...
</VirtaulHost>
```

Which works perfectly. Then I want to redirect one request to a static page, which is from https://shopecific.com/amzvar to https://shopecific.com/amzvar.html

But I tried the following rewrite rules, but none of those works:

```
# RewriteRule ^/amzvar$, /amzvar.html [R,L]
# RewriteRule ^/amzvar$, https://shopecific.com/amzvar.html [R,L]
# RedirectMatch 301 ^/amzvar$ https://shopecific.com/amzvar.html
```

Somehow those rules are just got ignored, and I always got the not found page. Note that "amzvar" is not a defined route on the Node.js. I understand that by the following rule in routers.js, it could be redirected to "not found".

```
<Route path="*" component={NotFound} status={404} />
```

However, the Apache Rule should be matched first, right?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try placing them right after `RewriteEngine On` (befory proxying to node)?

Comment: Yes. I did @DusanBajic And you see I added 'L' flag to tell it's the last rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is related to Service Worker. Somehow React-Router V3 and Service Worker does not work together to handle undefined router (i.e., it will redirect to default route () regardless other rules even in the Apache config.